# Storing MongoDB database credentials inside Android app

Tags: java, android, mongodb, apk, dalvik

I have developed an android app that directly interacts with the MongoDB for insertion and fetching the data.

I have credentials stored inside a config file of android app that I read inside the app.

```
mongoDBConnection:
  credentials:
    username: "test"
    password: "test"

  database: "admin"
  connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017"
```

The app works as expected when installed on a phone, the worry that I have is if I ship the app can anyone decompile the app and retrieve the credentials back?

To solve the issue, the android app can interact with a backend which will route requests to mongoDB and monogo credential are stored in that backend.

I wanted to get inputs on before implementing the backend on whether a backend is required or is there any way in android app itself to store the credentials such that it does not get exposed when decompiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I ship the app can anyone decompile the app and retrieve the credentials back?

Yes.

> is there any way in android app itself to store the credentials such that it does not get exposed when decompiled?

No, this isn't possible.  You can obfuscate them to make it harder, but it's impossible to prevent a sufficiently skilled/determined attacker from retrieving them if the app has them.

> To solve the issue, the android app can interact with a backend which will route requests to mongoDB and monogo credential are stored in that backend.

This is the only way to do this, and the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

> if I ship the app can anyone decompile the app and retrieve the
>   credentials back?

Technically yes. But if you use proguard it will be really hard for someone to figure out your DB credentials. This can be your first line of defense

> is there any way in android app itself to store the credentials such
>   that it does not get exposed when decompiled?

Yes. Use Keystore.
Follow this [article](https://medium.com/@ericfu/securely-storing-secrets-in-an-android-application-501f030ae5a3)

Comment: None of this is correct.  ProGuard might slow them down by a couple minutes because they can't just search by symbol name for "password", but they could still easily dump all the string constants, and it wouldn't help at all if they're in a file.
KeyStore won't help because you need some way to get the credentials to the KeyStore in the first place, which just gets you right back to the starting question.

Comment: @RyanMentley Well, That's why I said Proguard is only your 1st line of defense. And I said keystore is a way  in android app itself to store the credentials such that it does not get exposed when decompiled. That's why I highlighted it. Its not the solution if you have stored your credentials in your code.